# Scrapy How to run function after all pages being crawled

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, pipeline

Because I want to format the XML output below are my code on Pipelines:

```
class TutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('outs.xml', 'a')
        self.file.write('<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>')
        self.file.write('<Friends>')
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.file.write('</Friends>')
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        escape("< & >")
        self.file.write('<friend id=\"' + item['id'] + '\">')
        self.file.write('<birthdate>' + item['birthdate'] + '</date>')
        self.file.write('<user>' + item['user'] + '</user>')
        self.file.write('<review>' + escape(item['review'].encode('utf-8').strip()) + '</review>')
        self.file.write('</item >')
        return item
```

Below are my Spider how I do crawling with multiple pages:

```
class SavoySpider(BaseSpider):
    # identifies of the Spider
    name = "friend"
    count = 0
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/biz/social/"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(0,1000,40):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.example.com/biz/social/?start=%d" % i)

    def parse(self, response):
        response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br />', '\n')) 
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = FriendItem()
            self.count += 1
            item['id'] = str(self.count)
            item['birthdate'] = str(site.select('.//div/div/meta[@itemprop="birthdate"]/@content').extract()[0])
            item['user'] = site.select('h4/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['review'] = ''.join(site.select('.//div[@class="media-friend"]/p/text()').extract())
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

But what problem now is if I using Pipelines to customize the xml format, when crawl another page the  will be appended below and subsequent pages. The output will become like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Friends>
  <friend id = "1">
     <name>Name1</name>
     <birthdate>1988-04-03</birthdate>
     <review>txt............</review>
  </friend>
  .....
</Friends>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Friends>
  <friend id = "40">
     <name>Name41</name>
     <birthdate>1988-04-13</birthdate>
     <review>txt............</review>
  </friend>
  .....
</Friends>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Friends>
  <friend id = "81">
     <name>Name81</name>
     <birthdate>1988-04-23</birthdate>
     <review>txt............</review>
  </friend>
  .....
</Friends>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want the output to be written to different files?

Answer (score 2):

I use [spider-closed](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/signals.html#spider-closed) signals to do things after a spider has been closed.